# What is the better way to remove first ":" only using split?

Tags: java, string, split

How to split the first `:` only ?

Eg. I have a `String` time, which holds `Time : 5:40`

Now I want to split the string and get value `5: 40` only.

```
 public static String SplitTime(String time)
    {

            String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":");
            String a=altSplitTime[1];
           Log.e("A",a);
            return String.valueOf(a);

    }
```

But I get output `5` only. What is the better way to solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf  method(). It will return the first index of :. and then do accordingly.
`String temp= time.substring(time.indexOf(":"));`  
Please ignore syntax as I have not compiled it.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: where you get the str?

Comment: Its time in your case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as AnswerDroid explained.
It can be done by using the indexOf() and substring() method.

But, with just

```
time.substring(time.indexOf(":"));
```

The output would be like:

```
: 5:40
```

If you want you result to be like:

```
5:40
```

Use:

```
(time.substring(time.indexOf(":")+2));
```

instead.

Note:- You need to sent the argument **Time** with those equal number of white spaces before the **time** value.

Otherwise, you can use :

```
a.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

to remove them and use the above technique on that.

Comment: Thanks ! I wonder why I will get `: 5:40`. And now my problem solve :) the `+2` did the tricks

Comment: Great !!....Please dont forget to tick the "Accept this answer - resolved the problem".

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the existing answers, you can also use a variant of the `String.split()` method like this,

```
        String[] altSplitTime = time.split(":", 2); // Notice the 2 here.
        String a=altSplitTime[1];
```

The `2` in the split method makes the string to split into **2 parts at most**. So you will get your required answer.